# Do atoms have lifespans?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, proton-decay

From *A Short History of Nearly Everything* by Bill Bryson:

> Atoms, however, go on practically forever. Nobody actually knows 
>   how long an atom can survive, but according to Martin Rees it is 
>   probably about 10^35 years

Can anybody explain this result to me?

I am told that the original atoms in the universe were likely Hydrogen, condensing out of primordial big bang stuff.  Lighter atoms are said to come around as part of the fusion cycles that keep stars running, and heavier ones out fusions that occurs in energetic events like supernovae.  We also have radioactive decay to consider.  I'm fine with all of these things, but it sounds like Bryson is talking about something altogether different.

I see how you could make a statistical argument involving the likelihood of a given atom to be involved in future such events, but I don't think that is what's going on here as the result is twenty-five orders of magnitude older than the universe (as far as we know).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with the probability that the [proton would decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay) into lighter subatomic particles, such as a neutral pion and a positron, which is a calculable number depending on the theories existing at the moment. The limit in your quote is one order of magnitude higher than the latest experimental limit of proton decay up to now.

If a proton decays in the nucleus of an atom the nucleus disintegrates because it loses a baryon  and the energy released within will destroy it, and then the atom dissolves.

Comment: No one knows experimentally if the proton will ever decay, there is however an lower limit on its life time. it is predicted to decay by many GUT's.

Comment: @Prathyush: There is also an upper limit from standard model instanton mediated decay, which is enormous.

Comment: I did not know that thank you. can this instanton mediated decay be approximated by a Feynman vertex, after somehow calculating its contribution. I know what instantons are but their contribution to Feynman diagrams is very new to me.

Comment: Well even if all the protons got destroyed there will still be neutrons. These neutrons can undergo beta decay and turn into protons. So the atom can still last longer than that. Of course you are right about proton decay(it is not experimentally proven of course).

Comment: @RoghanArun atoms depend on electromagnetic interactions for their binding also. The nucleus will disintegrate once protons start decaying , first  with nuclear decays and then when all protons are gone the neutrons will be free to decay.

Comment: The atoms can then reform though for a second time.

Comment: @RoghanArun  not in the standar comology of Big Bang. There are other models  for a cycling  universe, not main stream. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model

Comment: No, I mean the atoms can form a  second time because the neutrons would have decayed to protons and electrons.

Comment: @RoghanArun only hydrogen could form and then protons would again decay, unless the universe is oscillating and continuous to the big crunch

Comment: That would take 10^32 years for the half life.

Comment: @RoghanArun Afaik the mechanism causing the (still hyphothetical) proton decay would work also for neutrons (and is not affected significantly that the nucleon is bound in a nucleus or is free). If protons decay, also the neutrons (bound in a nucleus) decay with similar stats. It is called "proton decay" only becaue the neutron decays far more quickly, by ordinary beta decay, if they are free.

Comment: But theoretically, new protons could be created by putting a lot of energy into a spot making protons and antiprotons. Then those protons can be used to replace the decaying protons.